# Rails 3: Path not responding in view but working in console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I can run this command on my console:

```
@user.relationships.find_by_followed_id(9)
```

But I can't use this on my view:

```
<%= form_for current_user.relationships.find_by_followed_id(9), :html => { :method => :delete } do |f| %>
```

The error is:

```
undefined method `relationship_path' for #<#<Class:0x00000100bdc008>:0x00000100bc1f50>
```

I can't figure it out why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you do not have a route for your relationship resource/model defined ...

Comment: Yes, I've figured it out just before you wrote. So stupid.. I've spent 60 minutes to figure it out. I thought the route was there. thanks.